# How to set default timezone in browser in timepicker js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I tried everything to set a default timezone in browsers for timpicker js but it's not working.

Here is the js i am using :
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

And its customization options are :
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Show some of the code you have tried, What's the problem, whenever the user clicks the now button it uses local time?

Comment: i tried to set default.timezone, actually i want to show +0400 timings to all the visitors on my site as i am using that time to execute the functionality. So now option should show the timings of +0400 GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
defaultTimezone: "+0400"
```

where +0400 is your preferred default time zone and you'll be on your merry way.

Comment: This doesn't work. I already tried this.